# Considering alphabet = {0,a} , What is the automata respresenting the language L = {w ∈ Σ^* : |w|0a = |w|a0} is regular?

Tags: computation-theory

This is my current fsm. The non straight lines signifiy a line pointing towards the states itself. I feel like it is not right but I can't tell what is wrong.
Thank you for your help
[This is my fsa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz85z.png)

Comment: Is that related to informatic or it is more about maths or algo ?

Comment: It's theory of computation so it's more math than algo

Comment: Mmmh ok so you will have more people that can help you on this stack blog: https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you so much!